# How to add grass64 to PATH variable

Tags: grass-gis, command-line

I recently installed GRASS 6.4 in a Unix environment. The application opens fine, but I would like to also be able to run the GUI from the command line. The tutorials says that the 
`grass64` command should bring up the GUI from the command line, but the command is not recognized, so I assume I need to add the path variable to my .bash_profile. I have looked everywhere and cannot figure out in which directory `grass64` is located. Does anyone know what path I need to add to make it work?

I tried adding the `/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/` path to my .bash_profile, since this seems to be the path that the app uses, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X, with the [Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) version, the directory where grass64 is located  is the application itself.
If you want to launch GRASS-6.4.app from the command line (Terminal), the path that the app uses is:

```
/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh
```

If you want to add something to your .bash_profile, use an alias

```
alias grass64=/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh
```

And you can call grass64 from the command line

The fact that GRASS starts with a GUI or not depends of the parameters in a file named `.grassrc6` (hidden file) located in your home directory

```
MAPSET: a_mapset
GISDBASE: /Users/you/grassdata
LOCATION_NAME: a_location
GUI: text  or GRASS_GUI: wxpython
```